# Block internal IP adresses with dnsmasq.conf

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, blacklist

One can do something like this in the conf file to block wan sites:

`address=/verystrangesite.com/127.0.0.1`

So if user tries to try something not-so-funny on my guest lan he gets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Unfortunately, this is not working for internal sites (routers, gateways, hwfw, ip cam), at least if they are reachable by IP only (don't know if it would work if I had something like my-ip.com instead of 172.16.1.54). What I tried looks like this:

`address=/172.16.1.2/127.0.0.1`

So, do you know the correct syntax to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct syntax to achieve this.

dnsmasq is only a DNS server – it *does not* sit in the middle of all network traffic, it merely responds to DNS queries and translates domain names to IP addresses. Your dnsmasq examples don't *block* the sites, they just spoof the DNS query results (and only if the client uses your DNS at all).

Clients trying to access a website directly by IP address *do not use* DNS to resolve it in the first place – the address has already been "pre-resolved", so to say. Therefore, there is *no* dnsmasq configuration that could possibly affect such connections.

Instead, to block arbitrary hosts by IP address, do it in your router's *firewall* (Linux iptables/nft/ferm, BSD pf). To generate a "connection refused" error message, add a firewall rule that will "reject" the connection:

```
iptables -I FORWARD [...] -d 172.16.1.2 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -I FORWARD [...] -d 172.16.1.2 ! -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Hi grawity, 
thank you for your answer.

Ok; as I am not that firm in router issues, let me ask another dumb question:
What I understood from your explanation is that I have to set up one of my machines as a Linux based router, right?
What currently works as my only router, isn't managable that way.
So, how am I able to create a router from a PC/mini PC/any device when there is only 1 ethernet port available?

Comment: Most home routers generally have at least basic firewall functions – if not 'reject' then at least 'drop' mode. It's rare to have one completely lacking a firewall... (Take a look at OpenWRT, TP-Link, Mikrotik, just about anything.) You can certainly build your own router, but with only one interface it'll be difficult – _unless_ you also have a switch with 802.1Q VLAN support. (Two VLANs can be used for routing just like two physical interfaces.)